# RegExp: Allow digits 0 to 1439 without any spaces for a textfield which supports both MySQL and Oracle

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I have a time field which allow (24*60)-1 minutes i.e. 1439 minutes.
Minimum 0 mins maximum 1439 minutes. For this I need a regexp.

Need a regular expression which allow only digits 0 to 1439 without any spaces between for a textfield which supports both mysql and oracle.

It has to allow 0 or 1 or 25 or 00 or 001 or 0000. But not 00 0 or 1440.

If possible give a single regexp which supports both mysql and oracle or else two separate regular expressions for mysql and oracle.

Comment: What does the time field look like?  Why not just use an integer?

Comment: Use `BETWEEN 0 AND 1439`. Don't resort to regular expressions for something that's much better handled another way.

Comment: Hi Gordon.. I'm sorry. Its just a text field which if type INT. But we have to allow user to input digits which should be in the range of 0 to 1339 digits . @Gordon Linoff

Comment: Also, 1440 - 1 = 1439, not 1339.

Comment: Omg.. I mistaken again. You are right @Phylogenesis

Comment: You can use [`^0*([0-9]{1,3}|1[0-3][0-9]{2}|14[0-3][0-9])$`](https://regex101.com/r/eF5bC5/2) if you need a range from 0 to 1439.

Comment: Unless this question is about the jQuery Validate plugin, please do not tag it as such.  Edited.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Stribizhev.It worked for me@Stribizhev

Answer (score 2):

If the value contains an integer, then cast to an integer and use `between`:

```
where cast(time as int) between 0 and 1339
```

However, you might need to be sure that the value is actually a numeric value (and you can use a regular expression for this).  I would discourage you from using a numeric expression for the comparison.  Although possible, the expression is convoluted and the intention of the code will not be clear.

Unfortunately, you cannot use:

```
where time between '0' and '1339'
```

Because string comparisons are different from numeric comparison (for instance, anything starting with '2' is not accepted by this logic).

Comment: I just need a regexp. I need to handle this from UI side itself. Before saving this field value, i need to display a validation message. Need a regexp in oracle and mysql both.@ Gordon

Comment: @Archana No, you really don't. You say you want to validate in the UI itself, and then talk about using SQL to validate? It's far far better to cast the value to an integer and do the appropriate numeric comparison.